# How to create a conditional insert function in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case, sql-function

I try to write a function to insert some values in `column3`  in my table based on values inside this table, but I'm not so familiar with writing functions in Postgresql 9.6.

```
--Create some table

    CREATE TABLE test(column1 INT, column2 INT, column3 TEXT) 
    INSERT INTO test VALUES(-8020,15),(-200,1),(23,115)

--Build function

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_function()
    RETURNS TEXT AS 
    $$
    BEGIN

        IF test(column1) <= -7000 THEN INSERT INTO test(column3) VALUES('small');
        ELSIF test(column1) >= -7000 AND test(column2) <= 15 THEN INSERT INTO test(column3) VALUES('nohello');
        ELSIF test(column1) >= -7000 ANDtable(column2) >= 15 THEN INSERT INTO test(column3) VALUES('test');
        ELSE INSERT INTO test(column6) VALUES("nodata");
        END IF;

    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The result should be a table that looks like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
---------------------------
 -8020  |    15   |  small
  -200  |     1   |  nohello
    23  |   115   |  test
```

While calling `new_function` I get the error `column1 doesn't exist.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be actually looking for an `update` (that changes values on existing rows) rather than an `insert` (that creates new rows).

But bottom line, I would suggest just using a computed column:

```
create table test(
    column1 int, 
    column2 int, 
    column3 text generated always as (
        case 
            when column1 <= -7000 then 'small'
            when column1 <= 15    then 'nohello'
            else 'nodata'
        end
    ) stored
);
```

When rows are inserted or updated in the table, the database automatically adjusts the computed column accordingly, so it is always up to date.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a17f9284b816ec4cb918adeee54e8c1)**:

```
insert into test(column1, column2) values(-8020,15),(-200,1),(23,115);

select * from test;
```

```
column1 | column2 | column3
------: | ------: | :------
  -8020 |      15 | small  
   -200 |       1 | nohello
     23 |     115 | nodata
```

---

Note that generated columns are available starting Postgres 12 only. In earlier versions, one alternative is have just the first two columns in the table, and to create a view to expose the third column:

```
create view myview as 
select
    column1,
    column2,
    case 
        when column1 <= -7000 then 'small'
        when column1 <= 15    then 'nohello'
        else 'nodata'
    end as column3
from mytable
```

You can then query the view instead of the table to display your data.

Comment: Create table test gives me "syntax error at or near "generated"."  Maybe correlated to my Postgresql version?

Comment: @DrSnuggles: indeed, computed column came in version 12. I edited my answer to suggest another solution, that works on earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

GMB's answer is the perfect solution, though you may update the table by using [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-conditional.html) conditional expression as shown below

```
update test
set column3 = case 
                when column1 <= - 7000 then 'small'
                when (column1 >= - 7000 and column2 <= 15) then 'nohello'
                when (column1 >= - 7000 and column2 >= 15) then 'test'
                else 'nodata'
              end;
```

[`Demo`](https://rextester.com/ZWL17392)